# 1920x1080 monitor only displays in 1776x1000 area

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, graphics

I have an ASUS VE276Q monitor (as a second monitor) connected to an ATI Radeon HD 4670 graphics card (system is a couple years old). For some reason the monitor will only display up to 1776x1000 resolution. Looks great at that resolution, but of course there's roughly a 1-inch black border around the image. If I set the resolution to the native 1920x1080, then it's a slightly blurry 1920x1080 image scaled down to the same physical area as the 1776x1000 image (1-inch borders around).

Any ideas? I'm using the latest graphics driver on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had this happen to me in the past. What you want to do is go into Catalyst Control Center and set Overscan to 100% under Scaling Options. This will fill your screen with the entire image and not downscale it.

Comment: I don't have any catalyst control center. I've tried installing the Catalyst Install Manager, but it only gives me audio drivers and an SDK.

Comment: @at01 Download and install Catalyst Software Suite from [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeonaiw-vista64.aspx).

Comment: When I try to install drivers directly, Win7 says I already have the latest drivers... How do I install the Radeon drivers otherwise? I've downloaded the AMD Catalyst 12.8 and Catalyst 12.9 beta suites. They only install Catalyst Install Manager to first detect what I need. It only detects that I need the things I listed above.

Comment: @Indrek - those are older drivers than I tried before, but I'll try that.

Comment: @AlanTuring That's not true, Catalyst Control Center is separate from the actual display drivers. It's possible to have installed the latter, but not the former.

Comment: @at01 Catalyst 12.6 seems to be the last version to support your card. As explained in the link I gave, the HD 2xxx/3xxx/4xxx series are considered to have exhausted their potential to benefit from newer drivers, and are thus considered legacy products. The [12.8 release notes](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalystSoftwareSuiteVersion128ReleaseNotes.aspx) confirm that newer Catalyst versions don't support those older cards, that's why the installer only suggests auxiliary software like audio drivers and the SDK.

Comment: yea sorry about that, i used a 5770 for a brief period 2 years ago, i have always used a geforce since then. The suite is bundled with the drivers for nvidia so i thought it was the same.

But as indrek said, 12.6 should allow for the access to the catalyst  control suite

Comment: Thank you @Indrek for the explanation. Wish AMD was a little more clear about this on their site. They ask me the graphics card I have, OS, etc and then present to me drivers that apparently don't work...

Comment: This fixed my problem! I feel like @Indrek should get a lot of the credit..

Comment: @at01 Glad to hear the problem is solved. Be sure to upvote the answer as well, and if you want to throw some credit my way, feel free to mark some of my comments as useful, by clicking the little up arrow (only shown when you hover the mouse over the comment).